# How to use an image in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am very new to Qt and trying

```
import QtQuick 2.5
Image {
    id: root
    source: "Background.png"
}
```

in Qt Quick Application
and getting the following error

> qrc:/main.qml:3:1: QML Image: Cannot open: qrc:/Background.png

In response to similar but older questions it is suggested that we need to put the image in the Resource folder, but Resources folder is just a pseudo folder, not visible in folder tree.
So how may I put the image in Resources folder or how may I use it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Qt resource system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html). In essence, you'll create a `.qrc` file where you list your resources, and add it to the `RESOURCES` variable in the application `.pro` file. You can do all this in Qt Creator as well, and the default Qt Quick Application templates already have resources setup, so all you need is to add your `background.png` there.

Comment: Though this works, I wonder if there is no solution, that allows to show pictures, that are not added to the qrc.  A use-case would be an image viewer, where the user should be able to add pictures during run-time.

Comment: You can. It's just that your main.qml is in qrc:/ so Qt tries to lookup background.png in the same place. If you put it on the file system instead, you need to tell Qt where it is by using a full path. Qt cannot guess or scan the file system to find out where "background.png" is. :)

Comment: It is common to use relative paths, which are usually well defined.
The problem here is, that the QML is listed as a resource already, so all the relative paths are relative to the closed resource-system. It is possible to use relative image paths, if your QML-file is not in the resource system itself. With all its implications.

Comment: Yes. The Qt resource system is basically a virtual file system. You can't use relative paths between two different file systems. It doesn't matter if the files would have relative locations in the source tree at development time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use source: "file:///C:/Users/your_user/Images/Image.png"
If don't have the image added to your qrc resource you can use the absolute image path but you will have an issue if you deploy the application and the image path changes.